# Debugging Self Tracking Entities - AcceptChanges exception due to object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, self-tracking-entities, objectcontext

I have an exception occurring when saving changes to a self tracking entity:

```
AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges.
```

I believe the problem is addressed in other questions such as: [Self Tracking Entities - AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350359)

My question is what is the best way to debug this problem both in development and production.  Is there any further information that can be caught/accessed which will detail which entities or the entity types which are causing the exception.

If not will I have to write something to traverse the object graph looking for duplicate keys referencing different objects?  If so does anyone have experience of this?

**Further info:**

My scenario involves the following - the client retrieves an entity via a WCF service which contains collections of further entities all with various FKs to other entities.  These FK relationships are all included in the linq query so we have a complete object graph.

The views in the client use previously fetched entities for static data such as lookup tables for performance.  If we have say a Customer object with a FK to User this will be loaded when retrieved from the service.  If we now add another entity to the object graph e.g. Order and set a User property on this object which has the same Id as in the Customer object but the entity was retrieved at a different point and therefore using a different ObjectContext (i.e. the objects have the same Id but are not the same instance of the object) I get this error.

The link to the other question demonstrates ways to avoid this but I am looking to find more information about which entities are causing the problem so I can track down the error.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens if you try to `AcceptChanges` on the context which was used to load entities before - use new empty context for accepting changes. `AcceptChanges` cannot be used when any entity from STE is already loaded in the context - that is limitation of current STE implementation (but it can probably be removed if you rewrite the template).

As I know there are no detailed exceptions for this kind of problems. For debugging STEs check their generated code. You have whole STE code available so you can browse change tracker and search for entities but it will not be easy.

I'm actually not sure if it is even possible to define duplicates on the client but let's suppose that it is. If you have the control over client code the best way is diagnose the client code. Add some logging and find the reason for duplications. Then remove the duplication because fixing the issue on the client will be easier then fixing the issue on the service. If you don't have control over the client I would say that it is a problem of incorrect data passed to your client and let client's developers to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am going to edit my question to provide more information

Answer (score 0):

I had been banging my head against this problem for more hours than I cared to admit. Finally found that the cause of the problem was that I had listened to the ReSharper hint to make my 
context provider static. since that occurred with a variety of other changes, I didn't think to check it as being the culprit. But in my case, that was the issue.