# STE Update & Delete struggle in an N-TIER application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, entity-framework, self-tracking-entities

We've been building an application which has 2 parts.
**Server Side:** A WCF service, **Client Side:** A WPF app following MVVM patterns

So we also use Self Tracking Entities to get some database job done but we're having struggles.

Here's an example code:

```
public bool UpdateUser(User userToUpdate)
{
    using (DBContext _context = new DBContext())
    {
        try
        {
            userToUpdate.MarkAsModified();
            _context.Users.ApplyChanges(userToUpdate);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // LOGS etc.
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

So when I call this function from the client, it gives us this exception:

> AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict
>   with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key
>   values are unique before calling AcceptChanges.

"User" entity has one "many-to-1..0 (UserType)" and five "0..1-to-many" associations.
And that "UserType" has a "many-to-many (Modules)" association.

When we send a User instance to this function, UserType is included with it's Modules.

If you can guide me through solving this problem, that'd be great.

Thank you.

Comment: It is issue of STEs - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350359/self-tracking-entities-acceptchanges-cannot-continue-because-the-objects-key Follow the link provided in accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you. I'm reading the post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolved this issue as a reference for the others having the same issue with me.

```
public bool UpdateUser(User userToUpdate)
{
    using (DBContext _context = new DBContext())
    {
        try
        {
            User outUser = usersModel.Users.Single(x => x.UserId == userToUpdate.UserId);
            outUser = userToUpdate;
            _context.ApplyCurrentValues("Users", outUser);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // LOGS etc.
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```